# Is there a way to modify the length of an Angular array using Cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress

I have looked all over but can't seem to find a solution to this. I have the following code...

```
<div id=test">
   <ng-container *ngIf="(myArray | myPipe)?.length > 0; else showOtherPanel">

      shows here if array is > 0

   </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #showOtherPanel>

   shows here if array is 0

</ng-template>
```

Is there a way to directly modify the 'length' of myArray to force it to always be 0 using Cypress, thus always showing #showOtherPanel?

I've tried something like...

```
cy.get(#test).invoke('attr', '*ngIf', '(myArray)?.length = 0')
```

...but I get an error 'Cannot set property message of [object DOMException] which only has a getter

Comment: Don't do that, your E2E tests shouldn't even know which framework the UI uses. What actual app _behaviour_ causes the array to be empty?

Comment: `*ngIf="myArray | myPipe | isEmptyPipe"` Try to create your own `isEmptyPipe`

Comment: I'm trying to only test the front end, rather than E2E, and ensure that the otherPanel will always display when the array is 0. I thought there might have been a way to interact with that value using Cypress.